# Android - Fatal Exception: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError in WebViewCore

Tags: java, android, junit

Since a few days ago Crashlytics gives us some strange exceptions.

This crash only occurs in Android 4.1 versions (82% in 4.1.2 and 17% in 4.1.1). 42% of the devices are LGE, 31% are Samsung and 7% are TCT.

```
Fatal Exception: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
Expected: <null> but was: Handler (android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread$1) {41e3f3a8}
junit.framework.Assert.fail (Assert.java:50)
junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue (Assert.java:20)
junit.framework.Assert.assertNull (Assert.java:237)
junit.framework.Assert.assertNull (Assert.java:230)
android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run (WebViewCore.java:1004)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:856)
```

There's also a second one:

```
Fatal Exception: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
junit.framework.Assert.fail (Assert.java:47)
junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue (Assert.java:20)
junit.framework.Assert.assertNull (Assert.java:233)
junit.framework.Assert.assertNull (Assert.java:226)
android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run (WebViewCore.java:684)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:856)
```

This one however only occurs on Android 4.1 versions (79% in 4.0.4 and 20% in 4.0.3). Affected devices are HTC 24%, ALPS 12% and Lenovo with 11%.

Anybody else ran into one of the issues / know how to work around that?

Comment: Maybe your app is still in debug mode?

Comment: @sivi Nope it's not. Also only around 300 users are affected by this and we have about 20k daily active users.

Comment: did you check http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.2_r1/android/webkit/WebViewCore.java/

at line 1004 there seem to be "key up" and those devices might have key up defined not defined and because of that: "null"

Comment: Yes that could be the case but nonetheless I've got no idea how to fix that

Comment: You can just add a check for those devices and operating system and if is one of them set some values for the "key up" so it will act like the back button for example as a redirect or just set it to a constant value boolean or numeric whatever it is.

Comment: @Niklas I am seeing the same thing.

Comment: @JaredBurrows we're still getting this. Have you found any solutions?

Comment: @Niklas No. I just commented last night saying I am seeing the same thing ha.